# Tooltip doesn't work in Google Scatter Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, tooltip

I'm trying to create a scatter plot using Google charts and I don't seem to be able to add a column to be a tooltip. I read various sources that state that the data definition should be as:

```
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); 
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');        
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        // A column for custom tooltip content
        data.addColumn({type: 'string',role: 'tooltip',});

       data.addRows([
          ['Name1', 1000, 'Tooltip string'],
          ['Name2', 1170, 'Tooltip string'],
          ['Name3', 660, 'Tooltip string'],
        ]);
```

However, it doesn't work.

[image]

JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/shakedk/c37L0d1n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

column roles are not supported by *material* charts,
along with several other options.

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

for custom tooltips, you will need to use a *classic* chart.

*material* = `google.charts.Scatter` -- package: `'scatter'`

*classic* = `google.visualization.ScatterChart` -- package: `'corechart'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
  // A column for custom tooltip content
  data.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip',
  });

  data.addRows([
    ['Name1', 1000, 'Tooltip string'],
    ['Name2', 1170, 'Tooltip string'],
    ['Name3', 660, 'Tooltip string'],
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    chart: {
      title: 'Example',
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('scatterchart_material'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="scatterchart_material"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of WhiteHat:

**ScatterChart + Tooltip + Dashboard filter column:**

I experienced with the ScatterChart that tooltips also do not work with the "arrayToDataTable method" IF there is also a string column that is used as the filter column of the google.visualization.ControlWrapper.

The "arrayToDataTable method" works well with just 2 columns with data and a 3rd column with the tooltip.

It also works well if the 3rd column contains the input for the dashboard filter.

But there is a 3rd and a 4th column then the "arrayToDataTable method" cannot be used (for ScatterCharts).

It works well if I use the DataTable.addRows method:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart_ecdf);
function chart_ecdf() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number','Population');
        data.addColumn('number','Area');
        data.addColumn({
            type: 'string',
            role: 'tooltip',
          })
        data.addColumn('string','Filter');
        data.addRows([
          [1324, 9640821, 'Annotated 1', 'A'],
          [1133, 3287263, 'Annotated 2', 'A'],
          [304, 9629091, 'Annotated 3', 'A'],
          [232, 1904569, 'Annotated 4', 'B'],
          [187, 8514877, 'Annotated 5', 'B']
        ]);
       
      var filter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'filter_ecdf',
        options: {
          filterColumnIndex: 3,
          ui: { caption: 'Kies een type', label: false, allowTyping: false, allowMultiple: false, allowNone: false, sortValues: false } },
        state: {'selectedValues': ['{{ .Params.ecdf_filter_state | safeJS }}']}
      });
      var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ScatterChart',
        containerId: 'grafiek_ecdf',
        view: {columns: [0,1,2]},
        options: { 
        chartArea: {top:10, left:35, width:'82%', height:'90%'},
        vAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 1, format: 'percent'},
        hAxis: {format: '#.##%' },
        legend: 'none',
        colors: ['#ffa852'] },
      });
      var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_ecdf'));
      dashboard.bind(filter, chart);
      dashboard.draw(data);
    }
```